# Having difficulty accessing the Java library AdwordsService Get Method and passing in Interface Class in ColdFusion

Tags: java, coldfusion, google-ads-api, coldfusion-11

Having difficulty accessing the Java library AdwordsService Get Method and passing in Interface Class in ColdFusion. I'm using ColdFusion 11.

```
<cfscript>


variables.File_Obj = createObject("java", "java.io.File");
variables.HTTP_Transport = createObject("java", "com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport").init();
variables.JSON_Factory = createObject("java", "com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory").init();
variables.HTTP_Request_Initializer = createObject("java", "com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer");
variables.Offline_Credential_Builder = createObject("java", "com.google.api.ads.common.lib.auth.OfflineCredentials$Builder");
variables.API = createObject("java", "com.google.api.ads.common.lib.auth.OfflineCredentials$Api");
variables.adwordsService = createObject("java", "com.google.api.ads.adwords.axis.factory.AdWordsServices").init();
variables.Budget = createObject("java", "com.google.api.ads.adwords.axis.v201506.cm.Budget");
variables.BudgetBudgetDeliveryMethod = createObject("java", "com.google.api.ads.adwords.axis.v201506.cm.BudgetBudgetDeliveryMethod");
variables.BudgetBudgetPeriod = createObject("java", "com.google.api.ads.adwords.axis.v201506.cm.BudgetBudgetPeriod");

BudgetServiceInterface = createObject("java", "com.google.api.ads.adwords.axis.v201509.cm.BudgetServiceInterface");

variables.Money = createObject("java", "com.google.api.ads.adwords.axis.v201506.cm.Money");

variables.adsession_builder = createObject("java", "com.google.api.ads.adwords.lib.client.AdWordsSession$Builder");

oAuth2Credential = Offline_Credential_Builder
    .forApi(Api.ADWORDS)
    .fromFile(variables.File_Obj.Init(expandPath('ads.properties')))
    .build()
    .generateCredential();
AdwordsSession = adsession_builder.fromFile(expandPath('ads.properties'))
    .withOAuth2Credential(oAuth2Credential)
    .build();
BaseServices = createObject("java","com.google.api.ads.common.lib.factory.BaseServices");
budgetService = BaseServices.get(AdwordsSession,BudgetServiceInterface);

writeDump(budgetService);

</cfscript>
```

Error
[image: error]

Is there an example of ColdFusion and Adwords Java integration out there? I tried googling and I didn't find anything.

CFDump of `AdWordsServices`.

[image: AdWordsServices]

[image]

Here is my attempt using AdwordsService

```
<cfscript>
variables.File_Obj = createObject("java", "java.io.File");

variables.HTTP_Transport = createObject("java", "com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport").init();
variables.JSON_Factory = createObject("java", "com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory").init();
variables.HTTP_Request_Initializer = createObject("java", "com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer");
variables.Offline_Credential_Builder = createObject("java", "com.google.api.ads.common.lib.auth.OfflineCredentials$Builder");
variables.API = createObject("java", "com.google.api.ads.common.lib.auth.OfflineCredentials$Api");
variables.adwordsService = createObject("java", "com.google.api.ads.adwords.axis.factory.AdWordsServices").init();
variables.Budget = createObject("java", "com.google.api.ads.adwords.axis.v201506.cm.Budget");
variables.BudgetBudgetDeliveryMethod = createObject("java", "com.google.api.ads.adwords.axis.v201506.cm.BudgetBudgetDeliveryMethod");
variables.BudgetBudgetPeriod = createObject("java", "com.google.api.ads.adwords.axis.v201506.cm.BudgetBudgetPeriod");

variables.BudgetServiceInterface = createObject("java", "com.google.api.ads.adwords.axis.v201509.cm.BudgetServiceInterface");



variables.Money = createObject("java", "com.google.api.ads.adwords.axis.v201506.cm.Money");

variables.adsession_builder = createObject("java", "com.google.api.ads.adwords.lib.client.AdWordsSession$Builder");


oAuth2Credential = Offline_Credential_Builder
    .forApi(Api.ADWORDS)
    .fromFile(variables.File_Obj.Init(expandPath('ads.properties')))
    .build()
    .generateCredential();


session = adsession_builder.fromFile(expandPath('ads.properties'))
    .withOAuth2Credential(oAuth2Credential)
    .build();
adwordsService.get(session, BudgetServiceInterface)
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Have you tried creating an object for the BaseServices and calling the get method there?  `BaseServices = createObject("java","com.google.api.ads.common.lib.factory.BaseServices");` and then `BaseServices.get(Session,BudgetServiceInterface.class);`

Comment: @Miguel-F I followed ur suggesstion and I got the following error.. I updated the question..

Comment: An exception occurred while instantiating a Java object. The class must not be an interface or an abstract class. If the class has a constructor that accepts an argument, you must call the constructor explicitly using the init(args) method. Error : com.google.api.ads.common.lib.factory.BaseServices
ErrorMessage com.google.api.ads.common.lib.factory.BaseServices
Message Object instantiation exception.

Comment: Can you post a link to the java code you are using as a base?

Comment: (Edit) Just a guess, but perhaps the code is using the wrong object to invoke `get()`.  You are using `BaseServices`, which is an abstract class. Those cannot be instantiated (which could explain the error). Did you mean to use the `AdWordsServices` variable instead?

Comment: @Leigh I tried it but I couldn't get access to the get method. Here is the GIST that I tried without any success. https://gist.github.com/mbejda/6bf884b979be2e49e39d#file-example-cfm-L38

Comment: (Edit) Never mind.  FWIW, a *very* brief search turned up a few CF a and "adwords" projects:  http://adwordsapilib.riaforge.org/ and http://www.cfsolutions.de/coldfusion_adwords_api/docs/index.cfm . No idea how current and/or useful they are, but might be worth a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100528/discussion-between-leigh-and-rastacide).